# Is $Z=e^{-\beta F}$ as general as $Z=\sum_{Ei}\Omega(E_i)e^{-\beta E_i}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I'm having some trouble understanding the formula: $Z=e^{-\beta F}$ which is sometimes used to define the partition function.

From what I understand, this $Z$, is the partition function but taken at the thermodynamic limit since:

$$Z=\sum_{E_i}\Omega(E_i)e^{-\beta E_i}=\sum_{E_i}e^{S_m(E_i)/k_b}e^{-\beta E_i}=\sum_{E_i}e^{\beta(S_m(E_i)T- E_i)}=\sum_{E_i}e^{-\beta F(E_i)}$$

And then, by taking the thermodynamic limit; we would find that $F$ is minimal at $E^*$ (which is approximatively equal to $\bar{E}$) and because $F$ is (inversely) peaked at $E^*$ we could write:

$$Z=\sum_{E_i}e^{-\beta F(E_i)}\simeq e^{-\beta F(\bar{E})}$$

And then, saying that $Z=e^{-\beta F}$ would be an approximation a bit like writing: $Z=\Omega(\bar{E})e^{-\beta\bar{E}}$.

Is this right? Or am I missing something?

**note:**

I'am not even sure I can write $E_i-TS_m(E_i)=F(E_i)$ since $S_m$ is the microcanonical entropy and not the thermodynamic one nor the canonical one (I guess?)...

Is it right too, to write $F$ as a function of the energy, in this case? Since it is supposed to be a function of $V$ and $T$?

We could also define $F$ from: $F=\bar{E}-TS$ and then, from $S=k_b\frac{\partial T\ln(Z)}{\partial T}$ and $\bar{E}=- \frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial \beta}$ but we are still using a thermodynamic relation and not an "exact" one?

Comment: First, a general comment: it usually does not make sense to talk about "the partition function in the thermodynamic limit" as the limit does not exist, except in trivial cases (usually, $Z$ blows up exponentially with $V$). That being, said, you can take the identity "F(T,V) = -kT\log Z(T,V)" as *defining* the finite-volume free energy. This is interesting, for instance, when you want to analyze boundary effects or other finite-size effects. Of course, the "real" (i.e., thermodynamic) free energy density is obtained by taking the thermodynamic limit of $F(T,V)/V$.

Comment: (An interesting example: if you wish to provide a statistical mechanical definition of surface tension, then the most natural way is to introduce suitable finite-volume free energies in order to extract the contribution due to the interface, and then take the thermodynamic limit. See, for instance, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64201).)

Comment: As nobody is answering the second part of your question, I suggest that you read Section 1.3 of [this book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook), where an explanation is given as to why one would want to define $F$ in this way and how to make a precise version of what you suggest at the end of your post. (The canonical ensemble is treated on p.31, but you should at least browse through the previous pages of the section.)

Comment: @Syrocco, I think $Z=∑_{E_i}Ω(E_i)e^{−βE_i}$ is
more  general than $Z=e^{−βF}$. If the expression under the exponential does not give a maximum for some $E_i$, we cannot apply the Laplace method for large $V$ and get an approximation. In this case, apparently there is no normal thermodynamics, but formally we can write an expression for the partition function (see for example *primon gas*)

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist : You consider the expression for the partition function as more general than the expression $Z=e^{-\beta F}$ (which, as I say above, should be taken as *defining* $F$ in finite systems). Then what do you *mean* by $F$ in the expression $Z=e^{-\beta F}$? The link with the thermodynamic free energy can only really be done in the thermodynamic limit...

Comment: @Yvan Velenik, I'm not sure if I understood you correctly ... I mean by F in the expression $Z=e^{−βF}$ the expression for Z (β) is just written differently, where Z (β)  is the coefficient in the statistical energy distribution - (Gibbs distribution, which is more general I consider). If we do not have a peak in the distribution, then we have no link, so Z(β) and F(β)  just a tautology

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist Precisely, it is a tautology (well, strictly speaking, a definition of $F$ in terms of $Z$). I disagree that one can make any precise identification with the thermodynamic $F$ without taking the thermodynamic limit first. So, in this sense, the two identities (the one defining $Z$, the other defining $F$) cannot have different degrees of generality: they are just two definitions...